# Android Project - Saving JSON array to HashMap and Retrieving Map Values

Tags: android, arrays, json, hashmap

I am a complete noob with HashMaps and have spent the better part of a week trying to find what I need.

I am successfully parsing a JSON response from an HTTP request.  What I'm having trouble with is saving each data variable/value from each JSON row into a HashMap and then retrieving those data values later.

In my for loop where I'm parsing the JSON response, I need to make sure I'm using the correct syntax for the put command.

More importantly, in getBottles() I need to know how to set o1.setname_abbr to the first record in the HashMap for name.  I will eventually need to turn that into a for loop and assign all of the names from the JSON response and then get them all back from the HashMap in getBottles().

Many thanks for any assistance!

Here is my code...

```
    public class Bottles extends ListActivity {
        private int category_id;
        private int subcategory_id;
        String subcategory_idString = "false";
        String postQuery;
        private int bottleID;
        String name_abbr;
        String name_abbrArray[];
        String bottlePicture;
        private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null;
        private ArrayList<Bottles> m_bottles = null;
        private BottleAdapter m_adapter;
        private Runnable viewBottles;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bottleNameArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> bottleNamesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String name[];

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.bottleslist);

            String result = "";
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras != null){
                category_id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
                subcategory_id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("subid");
                if(subcategory_id==0){
                    subcategory_idString = "";
                }
            }

            InputStream is = null;
            //http post
            try{
                if(subcategory_idString==""){
                    postQuery = "my api call goes here";
                }
                if(subcategory_idString=="false"){
                    postQuery = "different api call goes here";
                }
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(postQuery);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }

          //convert response to string
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }

            try {
                JSONObject row = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray array = row.getJSONArray("response name");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    bottleID = row.getInt("id");
                    name_abbr = row.getString("name_abbr");
                    bottleNamesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    bottleNamesMap.put("name", name_abbr);
                    bottlePicture = row.getString("bottlePicture");
                }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing JSON "+e.toString());
                }

            m_bottles = new ArrayList<Bottles>();
            this.m_adapter = new BottleAdapter(this, R.layout.bottlelistimagelayout, m_bottles);
                    setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);

            viewBottles = new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    getBottles();
                }
            };
        Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewBottles, "MagentoBackground");
            thread.start();
            m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Bottles.this,    
                  "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
        }
        public class Bottle{
            public String name_abbrArray;
            //public String lastName;
            //public int age;
        }
        private void getBottles(){
            try{
                //will put this into a for loop after I figure out how to reference the HashMap values
                m_bottles = new ArrayList<Bottles>();
                Bottles o1 = new Bottles();
        o1.setname_abbr("I want to get the HashMap value of the first name here");
                o1.setbottlePicture("Pending");
                Bottles o2 = new Bottles();
                o2.setname_abbr("I want to get the HashMap value of the second name here");
                o2.setbottlePicture("Completed");
                m_bottles.add(o1);
                m_bottles.add(o2);
                   Thread.sleep(2000);
                Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_bottles.size());
              } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
              }
              runOnUiThread(returnRes);
          }

        private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            if(m_bottles != null && m_bottles.size() > 0){
                m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for(int i=0;i<m_bottles.size();i++)
                m_adapter.add(m_bottles.get(i));
            }
            m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
          };

        private class BottleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bottles> {

            private ArrayList<Bottles> items;

            public BottleAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Bottles> items) {
                    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                    this.items = items;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = convertView;
                    if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.bottlelistimagelayout, null);
                    }
                    Bottles o = items.get(position);
                    if (o != null) {
                            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                            TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                            if (tt != null) {
                                  tt.setText("Name: "+o.getname_abbr());                            }
                            if(bt != null){
                                  bt.setText("Picture: "+ o.getbottlePicture());
                            }
                    }
                    return v;
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I don't fully understand your question, but if you add every bottle hashmap to an arraylist (by the way I see you have an ArrayList<Bottle> what should be its purpose, look empty to me).

You can, then, loop your arraylist containing your hashmaps: `arrayListOfBottles.get(position)`

Comment: thank you - I'm getting closer, but not quite there yet.  I added bottleNameArray.add(bottleNamesMap); because you were right, the array list was empty. I can now reference bottleNameArray.get(0) and I get the first bottle name like this {name=sample bottle name}. I tried to reference it as bottleNamesMap.get(0) but that didn't work.  Also tried bottleNamesMap.get(name[0]) but it didn't like that syntax. I just need to get at the actual value of name in position i (in this case (0)).  Thoughts?

Comment: do it like this: `bottleNamesMap.get(position).getString("name")` that way you should get "sample bottle name"

Comment: I had to break it apart a bit, but your suggestion led me straight to what I needed - thank you for your help!!